# Cannot open merged file from PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Below is a function I'm using to create a simple pdf file merger using PyPDF2. The program works without errors and outputs a pdf file with the desired name. But when I open the output file with any pdf viewer, it throws the error: 'Cannot open file.'

```
def morger():
    morg = PyPDF4.PdfFileMerger()
    for file in fyles:
        morg.append(file)
    lokation = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = location, filetypes = (('PDF', '*.pdf*'), ('Text', '*.txt*')))

    morg.write(f'{lokation}.pdf')
```

I made another .py file and ran a simple script to merge two files that are in the same directory as the .py file. The merger works perfectly there, but doesn't when it's used like the shown code here.